# enable_if iterator as a default template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae, enable-if

I have a constructor like that :

```
class MyClass
{
    template<class TI> MyClass(TI first, TI last);
};

template<class TI> MyClass::MyClass(TI first, TI last)
{
    ;
}
```

I would like to enable this constructor only if TI is an iterator (that means TI has an iterator_category I think). How to do that in C++ 2011 using an enable_if as a default template parameter (in the declaration and in the definition) ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a template parameter is an iterator type or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335962/how-to-check-if-a-template-parameter-is-an-iterator-type-or-not)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends on what you want. If there are no other overloads, it can be ok with just *nothing* at all. The compiler will produce an error if a type is passed that doesn't provide the necessary operation.

If you really want to limit it to iterators, it's preferable to do so with a `static_assert`, since it produces an error with a nice custom error message, instead of "ambiguous function call, here are all the gazillion overloads I could find: *follows endless list of overloads*" or "could not find function, find it yourself".

If there is another templated overload that conflicts, then you do indeed need some enable_if thing. I wrote a blog post about [using enable_if with C++11 features](https://rmf.io/cxx11/almost-static-if/), and why default template parameters are not very good for that. I settled with something like this instead:

```
enum class enabler {};

template <typename Condition>
using EnableIf = typename std::enable_if<Condition::value, enabler>::type;


class MyClass
{
    template<class TI, EnableIf<is_iterator<TI>>...> MyClass(TI first, TI last);
};

template<class TI, EnableIf<is_iterator<TI>>...> MyClass::MyClass(TI first, TI last)
{ /* blah */ }
```

All that you need now is a trait for the test. I think testing for the existence of `iterator_category` is enough, but it should be done with `std::iterator_traits`, because pointers are iterators and don't have nested typedefs.

That can be done with the usual techniques that use SFINAE. With C++11, I do the following:

```
template <typename T>
struct sfinae_true : std::true_type {};

struct is_iterator_tester {
    template <typename T>
    static sfinae_true<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category> test(int);

    template <typename>
    static std::false_type test(...);
};

template <typename T>
struct is_iterator : decltype(is_iterator_tester::test<T>(0)) {};
```

All that said, this could have been done with the traditional technique of using a defaulted function parameter:

```
class MyClass
{
    template<class TI>
    MyClass(TI first, TI last,
            typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category* = nullptr)
};

template<class TI>
MyClass::MyClass(TI first, TI last,
                 typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category*)
{ /* blah */ }
```

Comment: Thank you for this very clear sum up. Your blog post about the possible danger of defaulted parameter template is very interesting.

Comment: Maybe it's time to write a book on "modern C++"?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335962/how-to-check-if-a-template-parameter-is-an-iterator-type-or-not
it checks whether `iterator_traits<It>::value_type` is void