# Template specialization for iterators of STL containers?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl, iterator

I am trying to write a template function similar to `std::to_string` that works for basic types as well as iterators of STL containers. But I am not sure how to write the templates specific enough to identify just the iterators.

What I tried so far is to try to use the `iterator` typedef in STL containers

```
  template<typename... Args, template <typename...> class Container>
  static string to_string(typename Container<Args...>::iterator s) { ...
```

A minimal example is attached below. The code compiles but the template function `My::to_string` fails to match the above signature, and treated `std::set<int>::iterator` as a default type.

My question is how to write this correctly in a generic manner, so that the template function `My::to_string` can pickup iterators, but do not confuse iterators with other standard template types like `std::string`.

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class My{
  //base case
  template<typename T>
  static string to_string(const T& t) {
    return "basic ";
  }

  //specialization for string
  template <typename Char, typename Traits, typename Alloc>
  static string to_string(const std::basic_string<Char, Traits, Alloc>& s) {
    return (string)s;
  }

  //Problem line: how to write specialization for iterators of standard containers?
  template<typename... Args, template <typename...> class Container>
  static string to_string(typename Container<Args...>::iterator s) {
    return "itor ";
  }
};

int main() {
  int i =  2;
  string str = "Hello";
  set<int> s;
  s.insert(i);
  cout << to_string(i) << ", " << str << ", "
       << to_string(s.begin()) << endl;   //didn't get captured by iterator spec.
}
```

Output:

```
basic, Hello, basic
```

Desired output:

```
basic, Hello, itor
```

Comment: The left of `::` is a non-deduced context. Also this probably isn't generally possible. What if two containers both uses a raw pointer as an iterator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only care about the *iterator-ness* of the parameter, and not the type of the container, then you can SFINAE out the other overload.

First make an `is_iterator` trait, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11899057/2756719):

```
template <typename T>
struct sfinae_true : std::true_type {};

struct is_iterator_tester {
    template <typename T>
    static sfinae_true<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category> test(int);

    template <typename>
    static std::false_type test(...);
};

template <typename T>
struct is_iterator : decltype(is_iterator_tester::test<T>(0)) {};
```

Now SFINAE out the wrong overload depending on whether the type is an iterator:

```
//base case
template<typename T>
static std::enable_if_t<!is_iterator<T>::value, string> to_string(const T& t) {
  return "basic ";
}

//specialization for string
template <typename Char, typename Traits, typename Alloc>
static string to_string(const std::basic_string<Char, Traits, Alloc>& s) {
  return (string)s;
}

//Problem line: how to write specialization for iterators of standard containers?
template<typename T>
static std::enable_if_t<is_iterator<T>::value, string> to_string(const T& s) {
  return "itor ";
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d0c1b0e27a7a70d).

Comment: Thanks. I see that your demo used `-std=c++1y`. I tried this with gcc-4.8.1, but it didn't compile, saying `error: 'enable_if_t' in namespace 'std' does not name a type`. Does this require gcc4.9?

Comment: @TingL replace `std::enable_if_t<...>` with `typename std::enable_if<...>::type` if your compiler doesn't support it.

Comment: Thanks, your solution works with `template <bool B, typename T = void>
 using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if<B, T>::type;`

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple if you constrain the iterator-specific overload to work with any type for which `operator*` is defined ([Live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5cbf6606b1163f7b)):

```
namespace My {
    // base case
    using std::to_string;

    // overload for strings
    template <typename Char, typename Traits, typename Alloc>
    std::basic_string<Char, Traits, Alloc>
    to_string(std::basic_string<Char, Traits, Alloc> s) {
        return s;
    }

    // overload for iterators
    template<typename Iterator>
    auto to_string(Iterator i) -> decltype(to_string(*i)) {
        return "iterator to: \"" + to_string(*i) + '"';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This simplifies things.

Comment: Note that this doesn't compile if the type passed can't be passed to `std::to_string` and yet isn't an iterator or string. Also, `to_string('a')` will give you 97 since `std::to_string` doesn't have an overload that takes anything smaller than a `int`. Depending on the use case, this may or may not matter.

Answer (score -1):

It should be more like this:

```
template<typename ForwardIterator>
static string to_string(ForwardIterator begin, ForwardIterator end) {
    return "itor ";
}
```

Comment: to_string taking two parameters?  That's kind of counterintuitive

Comment: @MooingDuck: since all you can do with a single iterator is dereference it, a to_string taking a single iterator seems pointless to me.  What would be the benefit of `to_string(it)` over `to_string(*it)` which works already?  Perhaps I misunderstood the OP's question but it sounded like the point was to stringify a container.

Comment: @MooingDuck On the other hand most functions taking only one iterator are either pointless or wrong.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: I saw nothing in the OP about stringifying a container, but on the other hand, I can't think of any other possible use, so I guess two iterators does make sense.