# how to tell if a C++ template type is C-style string

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-traits

I am trying to write a template `is_c_str` to test if a type is a c-style string. I need this as an attempt to write a to_string function, as shown in my other question here:
[Template specialization for iterators of STL containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24848156/how-to-write-template-specialization-for-iterators-of-stl-containers).

I need to tell apart c_str and other types of pointers and iterators, so that I can represent the first at the face value, and render pointers/iterators as an opaque "itor" or "ptr". The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
template<class T>
struct is_c_str
  : std::integral_constant<
  bool,
  !std::is_same<char *, typename std::remove_reference<typename std::remove_cv<T>::type>::type>::value
> {};

int main() {
  auto sz = "Hello";  //Or: const char * sz = "Hello";
  int i;
  double d;
  std::cout << is_c_str<decltype(sz)>::value << ", "
        << is_c_str<decltype(i)>::value << ", "
        << is_c_str<decltype(d)>::value << std::endl;
}
```

However, `is_c_str` captures not only `const char *`, but also `int` and `double`. The above code outputs:

```
1, 1, 1
```

(as of gcc-4.8.1).

My question is how to fix `is_c_str` to properly capture c-style strings?

Comment: Is `remove_reference<remove_cv<int>>` not the same as `char *`? Why yes, that's true.

Comment: Why do you need this? Maybe there is an easier way to solve your original problem.

Comment: Be aware that `char*` is just a pointer to `char`.  It's not a C-style string unless it points to a null-terminated array.

Comment: @NeilKirk, Please see the P.S.

Comment: Is the type of `sz` really what you think it is?

Comment: @KerrekSB, Considering they said it captures `const char *`, maybe.

Comment: @KerrekSB I tried  const char * sz = "Hello2"; as well, same result.

Comment: Note that `wchar_t`, `char16_t` and `char32_t` can and are used for C-style strings as well.

Comment: To expand on dyp's comment: C-style strings are arrays of the member type, where the last one and only that last one is a 0-terminator. Pointers to them are pointers to C-style strings, but are not C-style strings themselves.

Comment: For your particular use case, I'd just add an overload of `template<class T> to_string(T * str);` and SFINAE it out unless `std::decay_t<T>` is one of `char`, `wchar_t`, `char16_t` and `char32_t`.

Comment: This would also catch `vector<char> vec(.....);` with `begin(vec)` if the compiler used bare pointers as vector iterators (which is permitted).  Maybe even consider rejecting `char *` entirely since there is no way you can validate if it points into a string or not; put the onus on the caller to supply the data in a safe manner.

Answer (score 22):

You want to check if the type is the same as a `char *`, but you're negating the result of `std::is_same`, which is clearly not going to produce the correct result. So let's remove that.

```
template<class T>
struct is_c_str
  : std::integral_constant<
      bool,
      std::is_same<char *, typename std::remove_reference<typename std::remove_cv<T>::type>::type>::value
> {};
```

However, this is now going to result in the output `0, 0, 0`. The problem now is that [`remove_cv`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv) removes top-level cv-qualifiers, but the `const` in `char const *` is not top-level.

---

If you want to match both `char *` and `char const *` the easiest solution is:

```
template<class T>
struct is_c_str
  : std::integral_constant<
      bool,
      std::is_same<char *, typename std::remove_reference<typename std::remove_cv<T>::type>::type>::value ||
      std::is_same<char const *, typename std::remove_reference<typename std::remove_cv<T>::type>::type>::value
> {};
```

The above version will still not match `char[]`. If you want to match those too, and reduce the verbosity of combining `std::remove_reference` and `std::remove_cv`, use [`std::decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) instead.

```
template<class T>
struct is_c_str
  : std::integral_constant<
      bool,
      std::is_same<char const *, typename std::decay<T>::type>::value ||
      std::is_same<char *, typename std::decay<T>::type>::value
> {};
```

Comment: You can reduce the verbosity even more by using `std::decay_t`.

Comment: @Snps The question is not tagged [tag:c++1y], otherwise I agree with you.

Comment: You can trivially disprove an argument being a C-Style string, if it has the wrong type (i.e. not type array of string-member-type). You cannot do so if it has type array of string-member-type of unknown length. Also, for pointers to a string the problem is magnified: You need also the element-number.

Answer (score 9):

I tried this and it seems to work:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct is_c_str : std::integral_constant<bool, false> {};

template<>
struct is_c_str<char*> : std::integral_constant<bool, true> {};

template<>
struct is_c_str<const char*> : std::integral_constant<bool, true> {};

int main() {
  auto sz = "Hello";
  int i;
  double d;
  std::cout << is_c_str<decltype(sz)>::value << ", "
        << is_c_str<decltype(i)>::value << ", "
        << is_c_str<decltype(d)>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Obviously enumerating every case is not as elegant as putting the general predicate in `std:integral_constant`, but on the other hand that predicate is alien tongue for idiots like me, while the "brute force" template specialization is somewhat more comprehensible, and viable in this case as there are few specializations.

Comment: There are actually more that this and other answers don't address -- such as `wchar_t`, `char`, `unsigned char`, `char16_t`, and `char32_t`.

Comment: @Rapptz I looked into it; there's no `std::is_character_type` so you just have to hard-code such a list.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Yeah, it's quite a shame honestly. A trait like that is pretty easy to define yourself but still sad that the standard library doesn't provide one.

Comment: Also works with using std::true_type and std::false_type.

Answer (score 8):

The type of `sz` is `char const*`, but `std::remove_cv<>` only removes top-level `const`, so you can't get `char*` through its application. Instead, you can just check for a `char const*` after completely decomposing the type with `std::decay<>`:

```c++
namespace detail
{
    template<class T>
    struct is_c_str : std::is_same<char const*, T> {};
}

template<class T>
struct is_c_str : detail::is_c_str<typename std::decay<T>::type> {};

int main() {
  auto sz = "Hello";
  int i;
  double d;
  std::cout << is_c_str<decltype(sz)>::value << ", "
            << is_c_str<decltype(i)>::value << ", "
            << is_c_str<decltype(d)>::value << std::endl;
}
```

You were also falsely negating the condition. I fixed that as well.

<kbd>[Live Example](http://rextester.com/IJG68841)</kbd>

Comment: The type of `sz` is `const char *` because `auto` is specified to decay arrays.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few solutions already, but since the simplest solution is really simple, I'll jot it down here.

```
template< typename, typename = void >
struct is_c_str
    : std::false_type {};

template< typename t >
struct is_c_str< t *,
    typename std::enable_if< std::is_same<
        typename std::decay< t >::type,
        char
    >::value >::type
>
    : std::true_type {};
```

The tricky part, of course, is analyzing what's inside the pointer type instead of the pointer type itself.

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of problems.

1. The line

   ```
   !std::is_same<char *, typename std::remove_reference<typename std::remove_cv<T>::type>::type>::value
   ```

   needs to be

   ```
   std::is_same<char *, typename std::remove_reference<typename std::remove_cv<T>::type>::type>::value
   ```
2. Your logic of using `typename std::remove_reference<typename std::remove_cv<T>::type>::type>::value` is flawed. It does not convert `char const*` to `char*`. It can convert `char* const` to `char*`.

What you need is:

```
template<class T>
struct is_c_str
  : std::integral_constant<
  bool,
  std::is_same<char *, typename std::remove_reference<typename std::remove_cv<T>::type>::type>::value ||
  std::is_same<char const*, typename std::remove_reference<typename std::remove_cv<T>::type>::type>::value
> {};
```