# How to define a template function with two relative parameters

Tags: c++, templates, functor

I'm trying to define a function, which allows us to call the standard hash function or some custom-defined function, and return the value of hash.

Here is an example about how to use my function:

```
auto res = myfunc<std::hash>(2);    //hash the integer 2 with the function std::hash
auto res2 = myfunc<std::hash>("abc");    // hash the string "abc" with the function std::hash
auto res3 = myfunc<customHasher>(2);    // hash the integer 2 with some custom hash function
```

I've tried to code as below:

```
template<void (*T)(U)>
size_t myfunc(const U &u)
{
    return T<U>(u);
}
```

`T` should be a function pointer, a `std::function` or a lambda, and `U` is the type of parameter of `T`.

But it can't be compiled.

```
main.cpp:14:23: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘(’ token
     template<void (*T)(U)>
                       ^
main.cpp:15:25: error: ‘U’ does not name a type
     size_t myfunc(const U &u)
                         ^
main.cpp: In function ‘size_t myfunc(const int&)’:
main.cpp:17:18: error: ‘U’ was not declared in this scope
         return T<U>(u);
```

Well, I know that `template<void (*T)(U)>` must be wrong because `U` is not defined. But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: `std::hash` is not a function. Fixing your attempt at a function pointer (assuming it's possible) still won't get you much further.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica OK, I added one line in my post: "T should be a function pointer, a std::function or a lambda, and U is the type of parameter of T.".

Comment: is `customhasher` a template? `return T<U>(u);` suggests that `T` is a template, is this needed or you could you pass eg `std::hash<int>` ?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Yes, customhasher is just like `std::hash`, which is a template with one parameter.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 That's the point. You see, I don't want to pass `std::hash<int>`, I just want to simply pass a `std::hash`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare both parameters. Moreover, `std::hash` is a class template, not a function. You can use a template template parameter:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T, template<typename> typename H = std::hash>
std::size_t myfunc(const T &t)
{
    return H<T>{}(t);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << myfunc(std::string{"123"});
}
```

Though, to use the same with your `customHasher` it needs to be a class template (with `operator()`), too.

Note that you need to explicitly construct a string in `main`, otherwise `T` cannot be deduced to be `std::string`.

Comment: Cool, did not know this. C++17 has this?

Comment: @kabaus c++98 had this ;)

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thanks man. One more question: is it possible to set a value by default for the first template paramater so that I can call it like this: `myfunc<>("abc");`, in which will call `std::hash<string>("abc");`.

Comment: @Yves no, because "abc" is a c-string literal, for which there is no std::hash specialization. [you will need to specify a string](https://godbolt.org/z/rnda6zqfb)

Comment: @JHBonarius  Could you please tell me why this is wrong? https://godbolt.org/z/99o5bGqvY

Comment: @JHBonarius  I'm trying to pass a C-style string and do a `if (std::is_same<char *>)` test in `myfunc` so that the caller could pass the C-style string but I got the error.

Comment: @Yves see edit. You need the string in main, inside the template the string comes too late, because then `T` was already deduced to be `const char*`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818   Check this link: https://godbolt.org/z/azPYrsjdW   I'm trying to make it print `1111`, instead of `2222`.  lol

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855160/how-to-tell-if-a-c-template-type-is-c-style-string    The second answer works.

Comment: @Yves I'm no template wizard, but you could use overloading or specialization e.g. [link](https://godbolt.org/z/6rb9j8xGW). Edit: forgot that partial template specialization is not allowed for function templates. Overloading seems to work.

Comment: @Yves note that the conversion from c-string to std::string is not free. You could look into using the [`std::hash<std::string_view>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/hash) that supports multiple string formats (but is NON-owning)