# How to partially specialize a template by STL iterator template?

Tags: c++, templates, partial-specialization

I want to specialize a template by STL iterator template like:

```cpp
#include <list>

struct Tag0 {};
struct Tag1 {};

template<typename T>
struct get_tag {
    using tag = Tag0;
};

//Wanted by failed
template<typename T>
struct get_tag<typename std::list<T>::iterator> {
    using tag = Tag1;
};

//OK
template<typename T>
struct get_tag<std::list<T>> {
    using tag = Tag1;
};
```

I've read related topic [Template Specialization for iterators of STL containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24848156/template-specialization-for-iterators-of-stl-containers) and got to know that it was a `non-deducible context`. How to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Which information do you want from iterator? [`std::iterator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) might help.

Comment: [You can't obtain container type from its iterator type.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3017518/5376789), so `T` cannot be deduced from `std::list<T>::iterator`.

Comment: @Jarod42. No specific purpose, just some practices. Thank you for the advices.