# How to check if an arbitrary type is an iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator

This is an exact duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335962), except *that accepted answer is wrong*, so I ask it again:

How do you **correctly** check to see if a given type `T` is an iterator?

My attempt at solving it:

```
// Assume enable_if and is_same are defined
// (hoping for a solution that works for C++03 too)

template<class T>
class is_iterator
{
    static char (&test(...))[2];
    template<class U>
    static typename std::enable_if<
        !std::is_same<
            typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type,
            void
        >::value,
        char
    >::type test(U);
public:
    static bool const value = sizeof(test(0)) == 1;
};

struct Foo { };

int main()
{
    return is_iterator<Foo>::value;
}
```

on Visual C++ happens to fail with:

> `...\vc\include\xutility(373)`:
>   error C2039: `'iterator_category'`: is not a member of `'Foo'`

because `iterator_traits` is looking for a definition of `value_type` in `Foo`, which (obviously) doesn't exist.

I **am** aware that `__if_exists` is a possibility on Visual C++, but I'm looking for a portable solution.