# How do I write a function that can iterate over a generic type

Tags: c++, c++11, generics, types

I want to write a function like `print_all` described below.

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

template <typename V>
void print_all(std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, V> it) {
  for (; it != std::end(it); ++it) {
    V item = *it;
    // do stuff with item
  }
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> myvec (10);

  print_all(myvec.cbegin());

  return 0;
}
```

How do I declare `print_all` such that it can accept any iterator over type `V`?

### Edit

I want to do this in a typesafe way. A better example of a use case would be an accumulator

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

template <typename V, typename K>
K accumulate(
      std::function<K(K, V)> accumulator,
      std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, V> it,
      std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, V> end,
      K initial) {
  K sum = initial;
  for (; it != end; ++it) {
    V item = *it;
    sum = accumulator(sum, item);
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Now you see why this question is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750057/c-printing-out-the-contents-of-a-vector). I feel like there would be a typesafe way to do this where the compiler makes sure the iterator iterates over the correct type. That is why I hesitate to accept Steve Lorimer's answer.

Comment: `std::end(it)` will not work - iterators don't know about the container they're iterating over - you need to pass the end iterator in, found via `std::end(myvec)` or `myvec.end()`

Comment: Or pass a reference to the container itself and use `std::begin()` and `std::end()` on it to get the iterators.

Comment: Almost a duplicate, so here is a truck load of different ways to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750057/c-printing-out-the-contents-of-a-vector

Comment: You should move your edit into a separate question.

Comment: That's an interesting problem, @SteveLorimer . You far as I'm concerned, you answered the question as originally worded, and unfortunately Sam intended to ask a completely different question.

Comment: moved to here http://stackoverflow.com/q/34301584/1078199

Comment: Question for @Sam: Why make the copy with `V item = *it;`? Something sneaky up your sleeve I'm not seeing?

Comment: Stop thinking `std::iterator` is something special. It's not. Also, you should pretty much never write `std::function</*something containing deduced template parameters*/>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have the required overloaded [`std::ostream` operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt), you can just make the actual iterator your function template's type

```
template<typename IterT>
void print_all(IterT begin, IterT end)
{
    while (begin != end)
        std::cout << *begin++ << ", ";
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

As stated, this will only work if you have the requisite `std::ostream& operator<<(...)` overload.

You would call it as follows:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> myvec;

    // populate myvec...

    print_all(std::begin(myvec), std::end(myvec));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And if they want to ensure that it actually is an iterator, they can use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032771/how-to-check-if-an-arbitrary-type-is-an-iterator