# Why compiler said "candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'InputIterator'"?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I'm learning template and writing Vector, there is a constructor in Vector :

```
template <typename InputIterator>
Vector(typename __isInputIterator<InputIterator>::__result, typename __isInputIterator<InputIterator>::__result, const allocator &);
```

Template struct __isInputIterator :

```
struct InputIterator {
    constexpr static bool isInputIterator {true};
    //...
}
template <typename, bool>
struct __InputIteratorInferringAuxiliary {
    using __type = __falseType;
};
template <typename Iterator>
struct __InputIteratorInferringAuxiliary<Iterator, true> {
    using __type = Iterator;
};
template <typename Iterator>
struct __isInputIterator {
    using __result = typename __InputIteratorInferringAuxiliary<Iterator,
                __IteratorTraits<Iterator>::iteratorTag::isInputIterator
        >::__type;
};
template <typename T>
struct __IteratorTraits<T *> {
    using sizeType = unsigned long;
    using differenceType = long;
    using valueType = T;
    using reference = valueType &;
    using constReference = const valueType &;
    using rightValueReference = valueType &&;
    using pointer = valueType *;
    using constPointer = const valueType *;
    using iteratorTag = RandomAccessIterator;//isInputIterator tag in RandomAccessIterator class is true
};
```

Demo :

```
int arr[] {1, 2, 3};
Vector<int> vec(begin(arr), end(arr));//candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'InputIterator'
```

Why the compiler would say that candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'InputIterator'

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The code in the question is neither minimal nor reproducible.]

The issue is that parameters of type `cls<T>::type` are not deducible. This is the exact pattern you have in:

```
template <typename InputIterator>
Vector(typename __isInputIterator<InputIterator>::__result, typename __isInputIterator<InputIterator>::__result, const allocator &);
```

You simply have to reformulate the constructor so that it will be deducible:

```
template <typename InputIterator, 
         typename __isInputIterator<InputIterator>::__result* = nullptr>
Vector(InputIterator, InputIterator, const allocator & = allocator{});
```

This way, the InputIterator is deducible, and its validity is tested by the default parameter. This still won't do what you want, since in your partial code `__isInputIterator<InputIterator>::__result` is always defined to something. You want something that is SFINAE, i.e. defined only if this is an input iterator and undefined otherwise. You want something like `std::enable_if`:

```
template <typename InputIterator,
        std::enable_if_t<__isInputIterator<InputIterator>::__result::value>* x = nullptr>
 Vector(InputIterator, InputIterator, const allocator & = allocator{});
```

---

General comments regarding your code:

1. You should not use names prefixed with double underscores (`__`) since these names are reserved for the compiler.
2. The code is overly complicated for what it does. Look at the Stack Overflow question [How to check if an arbitrary type is an iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032771/how-to-check-if-an-arbitrary-type-is-an-iterator) for shorter ways to check if a type is an iterator.

---

This is code with minimum changes that works. **It is ugly, and I won't recommend using it**. It simply serves to fill up the gaps in the original question:

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
struct InputIterator {
    constexpr static bool isInputIterator {true};
    //...
};
struct __falseType 
{
    static constexpr bool value{false};
};
struct __trueType 
{
    static constexpr bool value{true};
};

template <typename, bool>
struct __InputIteratorInferringAuxiliary {
    using __type = __falseType;
};
template <typename Iterator>
struct __InputIteratorInferringAuxiliary<Iterator, true> {
    using __type = __trueType;
};

struct NotIterator {
static constexpr bool isInputIterator = false;
};
template <typename T>
struct __IteratorTraits {
    using iteratorTag = NotIterator;
};

struct RandomAccessIterator {
        static constexpr bool isInputIterator = true;

};

template <typename T>
struct __IteratorTraits<T *> {
    using sizeType = unsigned long;
    using differenceType = long;
    using valueType = T;
    using reference = valueType &;
    using constReference = const valueType &;
    using rightValueReference = valueType &&;
    using pointer = valueType *;
    using constPointer = const valueType *;
    using iteratorTag = RandomAccessIterator;//isInputIterator tag in RandomAccessIterator class is true
};

template <typename Iterator>
struct __isInputIterator {
    using __result = typename __InputIteratorInferringAuxiliary<Iterator,
                __IteratorTraits<Iterator>::iteratorTag::isInputIterator
        >::__type;
};
template <class T, class allocator=std::allocator<T>>
class Vector
{
    public:
    template <typename InputIterator,
            std::enable_if_t<__isInputIterator<InputIterator>::__result::value>* x = nullptr>
     Vector(InputIterator, InputIterator, const allocator & = allocator{});
       T* begin();
       T* end();
};
int main()
{
    int arr[] {1, 2, 3};
Vector<int> vec(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));//candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'InputIterator'
Vector<int> vec2(1,2);//candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'InputIterator'

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`InputIterator` in `__isInputIterator<InputIterator>::__result` could not be deduced because it is in non-deducible context.

According to the section on "Deducing template arguments from a type", from CPP working draft (N4713):

> **17.9.2.5 Deducing template arguments from a type**
>   ...
>
> 4. In most cases, the types, templates, and non-type values that are used to compose P participate in template argument deduction. That is, they may be used to determine the value of a template argument, and template argument deduction fails if the value so determined is not consistent with the values determined elsewhere.
>      In certain contexts, however, the value does not participate in type deduction, but instead uses the values of template arguments that were either deduced elsewhere or explicitly specified. **If a template parameter is used only in non-deduced contexts and is not explicitly specified, template argument deduction fails.**
> 5. The non-deduced contexts are:
>      (5.1) — **The nested-name-specifier of a type that was specified using a qualified-id.**