# Docker threading pool port issue in c++

Tags: c++, docker, ubuntu, g++

I have a threading pool program in c++ that works on my windows machine in visual studio.  I'm pretty new to c++ and have never developed it on a linux based system.  I'm attempting to build the same program in a docker container using ubuntu and g++.  However, I keep getting the following error...

```
threadpool.h: In member function 'void ThreadPool::map(Func&&, Iterator, Iterator)':
threadpool.h:73:33: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class T, class> struct ThreadPool::is_iterator'
   73 |   static_assert(!is_iterator<end>::value, "End argument needs to be an iterator");      
      |                                 ^
threadpool.h:73:33: note:   expected a type, got 'end'
```

If I'm reading this right, it says that end needs to be a type, this error is generated from the below code....

```
    template <typename Func, typename Iterator>
    inline void map(Func&& f, Iterator begin, Iterator end)
    {

        static_assert(!is_iterator<Iterator>::value, "Begin argument needs to be an iterator");
        static_assert(!is_iterator<end>::value, "End argument needs to be an iterator");

        for (auto i = begin; i != end; ++i)
        {
            push(f, *i);
        }
    }
```

I think I'm declaring Iterator to be a typename, but it still has a problem.  The only other thing I can think of is that I'm not bringing in the correct libraries.  My dockerfile looks like this...

```
# Get the base Ubuntu image from Docker Hub
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Update apps on the base image
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y

# Install the Clang compiler
RUN apt-get -y install clang

# Install the G++ Compiler
RUN apt-get install -y g++

# Install Ruby
RUN apt-get install -y ruby

# Install Python
RUN apt-get install -y python

# Copy the current folder which contains C++ source code to the Docker image under /usr/src
COPY . /usr/src/threading

# Specify the working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/threading

# Use G++ to compile the Test.cpp source file
RUN g++ -o threading threading.cpp -lpthread -std=c++17

# Run the output program from the previous step
CMD ["./threading"]
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I can post more code if necessary!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using

[How to check if an arbitrary type is an iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032771/how-to-check-if-an-arbitrary-type-is-an-iterator)

for your is_iterator methods, you will notice that those methods check if a Type is an Iterator, while end is a function Parameter. So to compile it You can go:

```
static_assert(is_iterator<Iterator>::value, "Begin argument needs to be an iterator");
static_assert(is_iterator<decltype(end)>::value, "End argument needs to be an iterator");
```

Be aware that's redundant as both begin and end share the same type.

Comment: Huh.  I'm going to have to dig into this.  The answer worked, but I'm having an issue wrapping my mind around "end" being a parameter.  thanks for the link, I'll be taking a look at it!