# How to define is_iterator type trait?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, type-traits, c++14

- I'm trying to code a `is_iterator<T>` type trait. Where when `T` is an iterator type `is_iterator<T>::value == true` otherwise is `is_iterator<T>::value == false`.
- What I tried so far:

---

```
template <class, class Enable = void> 
struct is_iterator : std::false_type {};

template <typename T> 
struct is_iterator<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<typename
     std::iterator_traits<T>::pointer>::value>::type> : std::true_type {};
```

[<kbd>**LIVE DEMO**</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb885e13f924a320)

---

**Q:** Is there a more proper way to define a `is_iterator` type trait than the one displayed above?

Comment: Why does this need to be a whole class or struct? Why not have `bool is_iterator(T)`?

Comment: @Josh for use in SFINAE.

Comment: You could check for all the requirements of the iterator concept: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator.

Comment: N.B. pre-[DR 2408](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2408) `iterator_traits` is not SFINAE-friendly and instantiating it for a non-iterator type is a hard error, not a substitution failure

Comment: A type is an iterator if it is either an input iterator or an output iterator.  Defining `is_input_iterator<T>` and `is_output_iterator<T>` is left as an exercise for the reader. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I said in comments, the solutions presented here rely on non-portable properties of `iterators_traits` in some implementations. According to the C++03 and C++11 standards, `iterator_traits` is only defined for iterators (and the special case of pointers) so any other use is undefined behaviour. Specifically, using `iterator_traits<T>::pointer` in a SFINAE context isn't guaranteed to work, because instantiating `iterator_traits<T>` will refer to `T::value_type`, `T::pointer`, `T::iterator_category` etc. and that happens outside the "immediate context" where SFINAE doesn't apply.

C++14 <strike>will fix that</strike> was supposed to fix that (it happened post-C++14 with [DR 2408](http://wg21.link/lwg2408)), but for C++11 the safe way to define `is_iterator` is to write a trait that checks for all the required operations an iterator must define. The only operations that all iterators are required to support are `operator*` and pre- and post-increment. Unfortunately, there can be types that define those operations which are not valid iterators, so writing a correct trait is quite hard.

Comment: Jonathan, does your answer also apply to the propositions at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4335962/1593077)? Or is one of those a good enough "trait that checks for all the required operations"? Also, if a type satisfies all requirements of the iterator concept (which supposedly can be checked) - is it not ipso facto an iterator, albeit accidentally so?

Comment: Most of those answers are wrong (because they assume iterators will have particular nested typedefs), but Barry's answer is probably good enough. Yes, if a type satisfies all the requirements of a concept then it is a model of that concept.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Sorry for picking up an old question. You said "Barry's answer is probably good enough". Unfortunately I don't see a Barry. Did you refer to the answer with the time stamp Aug 13 '14 at 16:26 (currently by the username Praetorian)?

Comment: @C.Binair I was replying to a comment about a different question, and so I was talking about an answer to ***that*** question, i.e. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31409532/981959).

Answer (score 6):

Your check fails if `std::iterator_traits<T>::pointer` is a type that is not a pointer, for instance if [`T = std::ostream_iterator<U>`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/589538d283b1ecc6).

I think a better test might be whether `std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category` is either `std::input_iterator_tag` or a derived type, or `std::output_iterator_tag`.

```
template <class, class Enable = void> struct is_iterator : std::false_type {};
template <typename T> 
struct is_iterator
<T, 
 typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_base_of<std::input_iterator_tag, typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category>::value ||
    std::is_same<std::output_iterator_tag, typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category>::value 
 >::type> 
 : std::true_type {};
```

Comment: what about the other iterator tags? random, bidirectional etc

Comment: @IonTodirel All input iterator categories are derived from `input_iterator_tag`, see [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags)

Answer (score 4):

I think there's no need to check for any particular property of `iterator_traits`'s nested typedefs. It should be enough to check for mere presence of `iterator_traits<T>::value_type` (or any other nested typedef, for that matter), because every iterator has one.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template<typename>
struct void_ {
  typedef void type;
};
// remove typename spam below:
template<typename Discard>
using void_t=typename void_<Discard>::type;
template<typename T>
using decay_t=typename std::decay<T>::type;    

// stick helper types into details, so the interface
// for is_iterator is cleaner:
namespace details {
  template<typename T, typename Enable=void>
  sturct is_iterator : is_iterator2<T, Enable> {};

  // special case: void* is not an iterator
  // but T* specialization would pick it up
  // if there weren't the following:

  template<typename V>
  struct is_iterator<V*, decay_t<V>> : std::false_type {};

  // phase 2: SFINAE pass to std::iterator_traits test
  // valid in C++14, and in many C++11 compilers, except
  // for above void issue:
  template<typename, typename Enable = void>
  struct is_iterator2 : std::false_type {};

  template<typename T>
  struct is_iterator2<T, 
    void_t< typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type>
  > : std::true_type {};
}
template<typename T>
struct is_iterator : details::is_iterator<T> {};

int main()
{
    std::cout
        << is_iterator<int*>::value
        << is_iterator<double>::value;
}
```

Unfortunately this isn't guaranteed to work in C++11, but C++14 will fix it (thanks to [Jonathan Wakely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290462/how-to-define-is-iterator-type-trait/25292153?noredirect=1#comment39416925_25292153) for pointing it out).

Comment: But `iterator_traits` is not SFINAE-friendly in C++11, so instantiating `iterator_traits<X>` for a non-iterator type is undefined behaviour, and the error is not in the immediate context, so is an error not a substitution failure (http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2408 addresses that)

Comment: Luckily some implementations have been shipping a SFINAE-friendly `iterator_traits` for years, because it's a lot more useful that way :)

Comment: Many almost-SFINAE `iterator_traits` will fail horribly on `iterator_traits<void*>` (and cv variants).  (The `T*` specialization will catch it, but the instance will fail to compile)

Comment: Sadly, `void const*` `void volatile*` `void const volatile*` probably also break.