# How to use SFINAE to restrict overload to input iterators

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Many container class templates have, among others, a constructor that takes a count and a sample element as argument, and another constructor that takes a pair of input iterators. Other methods like `insert` exhibit the same pattern. A naive implementation will run into trouble when the template is instantiated with an integral type, and the constructor (or other method) is called with a pair of integers: their types being equal, the input iterator method will give a valid argument type deduction, but then fail to compile.

I'm looking for an elegant way to specify that the input iterator method is to participate in overloading only for (equal) argument types that are actually valid input iterator types, or at the very least not to participate for integer types. I have got the impression that SFINAE is the way to go (but would be delighted to be told differently), but when reading about it, frankly I don't quite understand the rules, and moreover the solutions presented in examples hardly qualify as elegant.

As a side restriction, I would like my code to comile with gcc 4.6 which has incomplete C++11 support. Notably I would like to avoid using template aliases. Here's my clumsy attempt (bare bones):

```
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template <typename I>
  struct input_iter : public std::integral_constant<bool,
  not std::is_integral<I>::value
  and std::is_base_of
    <std::input_iterator_tag
    ,typename std::iterator_traits<I>::iterator_category
    >::value >
  {};

template<typename T>
  struct container
{
  container (size_t count, const T& init);
  template <typename InputIt,
            typename = typename std::enable_if<input_iter<InputIt>::value>::type >
    container (InputIt first,InputIt last);
};

typedef container<int> int_cont;

void f()
{ std::vector<int> v (5,3);
  int_cont a1 (3u,6); // first constructor
  int_cont a2 (3u,6); // first constructor
  int_cont a3 (3,6); // first constructor
  int_cont a4 (3,6); // first constructor
  int_cont a5 (3,6); // first constructor
  int_cont b(v.begin(),v.end()); // second constructor
}
```

And here's a [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86f330466317ab88). The class template `input_iter` is trying to do things a bit redundantly: check that the type is not integral and then that it is actually an input iterator. Preferably I'd use just the second part, but that does not work; I get a template instantiation error when trying `int` for `I` (no `iterator_category`), and apparently this is not SFINAE. While I don't understand just why this is so, I added the first part to avoid the error, using the laziness of the `and` (`&&`) operator, but apparently to no avail. I can actually get this to compile by removing the second part of the condition, so my real question is not so much to get this to work in some way or another, but to understand what is going on.

One curious thing I noticed is that `g++` only gives an error message mentioning the definition of `a3`. So on one hand, making one argument unsigned apparently avoids trying the iterator overload (even though the other argument can easily be converted to unsigned), and on the other hand repeating the offending definition of `a3` for `a4` and `a5` does not repeat the error message (but if one repairs the `a3` definition, surely `gcc` balks at the `a4` definition). Also note that `clang++` does not point at any specific definition of one of the `a` variables, though repairing all of them makes it silent.

> What am I doing wrong, and/or should obviously be doing differently?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/25290462/981959 -- specifically be aware that prior to C++14 instantiating `std::iterator_traits` with something that isn't an iterator results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: Also, you need `::type` after the `enable_if` specialization. Otherwise it doesn't disable anything.

Comment: Look at immediate context for why SFINAE doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: Thank for the hint about a missing `::type`. I've changed that (both in the question and in the linked example); unfortunately it does not change much about the error messages I get. Also @Jarod42, I don't understand what you mean by immediate context; context of what? The definitions causing the error messages look perfectly normal themselves.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen He's saying that SFINAE only works in the immediate context of the declaration at issue. In particular, the reference to `typename enable_if<...>::type` is in the immediate context, so a missing `type` typedef in `enable_if<...>` causes SFINAE, but the reference to `typename std::iterator_traits<I>::iterator_category` in the definition of `input_iter` is not in the immediate context, so if `iterator_category` is missing from `iterator_traits<I>` you get a hard error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With help of the comments, and some more experimenting, I will try to formulate an answer myself.

I gather that Substitution Failure is only (SFI)NAE if it occurs in the "immediate context" of the relevant declaration, which is apparently a consecrated (but not very clearly explained) term used in 14.8.2;8 where it says "Only invalid types and expressions in the immediate context of the function type and its template parameter types can result in a deduction failure". Leaving aside that constructor methods don't really have any type, the failure/error in the example arises when trying to construct the defaulted type for the (otherwise unused) second template argument, but substituting a derived integral type for `InputIt` into the fragment `typename std::enable_if...::type`. Finding the value of the Boolean (nontype) template argument of `std::enable_if` is in itself performed in the "immediate context" (of the type substitution); the previous paragraph 14.8.2;7 is clear about this ("expressions include not only constant expressions such as those that appear in array bounds or as nontype template arguments..."). However computing that Boolean value requires forming the class template specialisation `input_iter<InputIt>`, and that is an auxiliary activity that is no longer performed in the immediate context. It turns out that during that template specialisation another template specialisation is performed, namely 
`std::iterator_traits<InputIt>`; this is not in the immediate context either, but this fact is irrelevant here since the latter specialisation never fails. However the resulting structure does not have an appropriately defined `iterator_category` member when `InputIt` is deduced to be an integral type, which causes the specialisation `input_iter<InputIt>` to fail in that case. Not being in the immediate context of the original type substitution, this failure make the program ill-formed.

So the real culprit, the element that separates the failure from the context where SFINEA would apply, is the specialisation `input_iter<InputIt>`, whereas `std::iterator_traits<InputIt>` is only indirectly involved. As a consequence, the example can be made to compile by cutting out the type derivation performed by the `input_iter` template, and feeding the boolean expression directly into `enable_if`. Since I wanted to avoid using template aliases, this requires (since there is no such thing as boolean-value templates) forgetting `input_iter` altogether and moving the whole expression it contained into the constructor template declaration, giving

```
template <typename InputIt,
          typename = typename std::enable_if<not std::is_integral<InputIt>::value
and std::is_base_of
  <std::input_iterator_tag
  ,typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::iterator_category
  >::value>::type >
  container (InputIt first,InputIt last);
```

The `std::is_integral` part is not really useful, and can be omitted, leaving just the `std::is_base_of` part. The resulting code [compiles and runs correctly](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40ea9b7c55484e9b), in fact even with gcc 4.6. This shows that in spite of appearances, one *can* use `std::iterator_traits` with SFINAE. When template aliases are available, one of those can be used to lift the `enable_if<...>::type` part out of the constructor declaration to make it look more appetising, but without them I cannot see how to do it and still correctly invoke SFINAE.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and answer, it helped me too.

Answer (score 2):

A fairly simple and straightforward way of doing it is:

```
// this wont collide
void assign( size_t, const T& );

template<
          typename It,
          typename = decltype(*std::declval<It&>(), ++std::declval<It&>(), void())
        >
void assign(It, It); // SFINAE on *it and ++it
```

Might not be good enough for submission to the standard, but 
I have used it in production, and it haven't bitten me yet.

If your compiler support expression-sfinae, there is a less clumsy
way to do the same thing:

```
template<typename It>
auto assign(It b, It e)
    -> decltype(*b, ++b, void())
{
}
```

With trailing return type, you don't have to use `std::declval`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need SFINAE for this. I would do it with `is_integral` and delegating constructors.

```
template<typename T>
struct container
{
public:
    container(std::size_t, const T &t);
private:
    template<typename I>
    // first is integral, delegate to size_t constructor
    container(I first, I last, std::true_type)
      : container{static_cast<std::size_t>(first), last}
    {}
    // first is not integral, assume we have iterators here
    template<typename I>
    container(I first, I last, std::false_type);
public:
    template<typename I>
    container(I first, I last)
      : container{first, last, std::is_integral<I>{}}
    {}
};
```

Comment: I like this idea. But some remarks: (1) with the sample program from the question, it still does not compile with gcc 4.6, presumably because that compiler version does not support delegating constructors; the error message is `error: type ‘container<int>’ is not a direct base of ‘container<int>’` (2) I've tried to do this with a defaulted template argument instead: `template<typename I, typename X = std::is_integral<I> > container (I, I, X);` but then I fail to find the right syntax to define, out-of-line, separate specializations where `I` is `std::true_type` resp. `std::false_type`

Comment: (3) The real reason this works as opposed to my attempt in the question is that `std::is_integral<I>` never fails to expand to a definite type for _any_ type `I`, whereas my `InputIter<I>` does fail to expand for integral type `I` (in spite of my efforts to handle that case), which as I now understand is a hard error. Using only `std::is_integral` (negated) in my attempted solution does solve my woes (as I observed in the question).