# Wrong Template Function Being Called

Tags: c++, function, templates

I have the following two functions defined in an STL-like List Container:

```
// copy the specified VALUE some COUNT number of times and insert copies
// right before POS.
Iterator insert(Iterator pos, size_type count, const value_type 
            &value);

// copy the values from [FIRST, LAST) from the specified Iterators and
// place before POS.
template<class InputIt>
    Iterator insert(Iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last);
```

I then tried to test my function implementations with some arbitrary code:

```
std::list<int> stlList = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
MyList<int> intList;

intList.insert(intList.begin(), 5, 0); // expected call to first insert
intList.insert(intList.begin(), stlList.begin(), stlList.end()); // expected call to second insert
```

However, for both of them it seems like the second function is being called. I kind of see the ambiguity, since both functions have three parameters, I see how the compiler may call the wrong function. But I'm not really sure what I am missing. I have been basing my functions off of STL and as far as I can tell, they defined them in nearly the same way ([STL's List Insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert)).

Comment: What is `size_type` defined as?

Comment: I think your `size_type` is unsigned, so the template method is an exact match. You may call `intList.insert(intList.begin(), 5u, 0)`

Comment: Notice the note regarding `std::list::insert`'s overload (4) (the one with two iterators) : "This overload only participates in overload resolution if `InputIt` qualifies as `InputIterator`, to avoid ambiguity with the overload (3)."

Comment: I defined size_type as such: `typedef std::size_t size_type;` in the MyList class.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux How could I make my function do the same thing?

Comment: You have to use SFINAE.

Comment: @ThomasPaine One way would be to use `std::enable_if`. You'll need to write a type_trait to check if a type is an iterator (it should have a specialization of `iterator_traits`). See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290462/how-to-define-is-iterator-type-trait).

Comment: I may be missing some higher-level reason for not doing so, but since the two functions are doing different things, wouldn't using different names (a) make the code more readable and (b) avoid any subtleties of template-matching? Perhaps `insertMultiple` and `insertFromRange` or something?

Comment: @TripeHound that is something I would do if I was coming up with this class myself, however, I am trying to mirror STL as much as possible and to make it STL compliant so I decided to stick to their conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `intList.insert(intList.begin(), 5, 0);` choses

```
template<class InputIt>
Iterator insert(Iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last);
```

over

```
Iterator insert(Iterator pos, size_type count, const value_type &value);
```

Is because the template function produces an exact match.

`5` and `0` have the same type so `InputIt` gets deduced as `int` which makes the function look like

```
Iterator insert(Iterator pos, int first, int last);
```

Where your other overload looks like

```
Iterator insert(Iterator pos, size_t first, int last);
```

As you can see no conversion is required to call the template deduced version so it is preferred over the non template overload.

You would have to cast `5` to a `size_t` to get it to call the non template overload or use SFINAE to only call the template overload when `InputIt` is really an iterator.

Answer (score 2):

```
template<class InputIt>
    Iterator insert(Iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last);
```

This template defines a function whose second and third parameters are the same type. You are assuming in your head that the second and the third parameters must be iterators. But there is no such requirement here, only that the second and the third parameter's type must be the same. The name of the template parameter, "InputIt", is irrelevant.

```
intList.insert(intList.begin(), 5, 0); // expected call to first insert
```

The second and the third parameter to this function call is the same type: an `int`. The other candidate for the overload resolution:

```
Iterator insert(Iterator pos, size_type count, const value_type 
        &value);
```

This one has different types for the second and third parameters. Although both ints can be converted here, the other template function is the better match, hence it gets selected.