# Partial specialization fails for container iterators

Tags: c++

I want to implement partial specializations for different container iterators. The code compiles fine if I do that for containers as such, but fails for their iterators:

**Good**

```
template<typename T>
struct IsContainer : std::false_type {};
template<typename T>
struct IsContainer<std::list<T>> : std::true_type {};
template<typename T>
struct IsContainer<std::set<T>> : std::true_type {};
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct IsContainer<std::map<T1, T2>> : std::true_type {};
```

**Produces error**:

> Class template partial specialization contains a template parameter that cannot be deduced; this partial specialization will never be used

for each specialization:

```
template<typename T>
struct IsIterator : std::false_type {};
template<typename T>
struct IsIterator<std::list<T>::iterator> : std::true_type {};
template<typename T>
struct IsIterator<std::set<T>::iterator> : std::true_type {};
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct IsIterator<std::map<T1, T2>::iterator> : std::true_type {};
```

What is the correct form for iterators?

Comment: I dont think it is that easy in all generality to decide whether something is an iterator or not. Maybe you can check it if there is a specialization for `std::iterator_traits<T>`

Comment: I dont completely agree with the duplicates. They answer the "why not" but the question here is rather about the "then how else?". Also the answer, while great, is only half of the answer

Comment: This answers the "then how?": https://stackoverflow.com/a/25292862/5470596

Comment: Aside from the difficulty (or impossibility) of deducing the parameters: your container trait will only work for containers with the default allocator. For the iterators, why not just use iterator_traits instead of specializing for each container?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler message is quite descriptive here. That is the way how compiler deals with template specializations. I'll try to explain why this would be impossible to implement from the compiler's point of view.

When you have the following code:

```
template<typename T>
struct IsContainer : std::false_type {};
template<typename T>
struct IsContainer<std::list<T>> : std::true_type {};
```

when compiler needs to instantiate `IsContainer<SomeType>` it needs to check whether `SomeType` is a `std::list` with some template arguments or not, and this is quite doable. If yes - it uses partial specialization, if not - the generic one.

Let's try do the same for the following code:

```
template<typename T>
struct IsIterator : std::false_type {};
template<typename T>
struct IsIterator<typename std::list<T>::iterator> : std::true_type {};
```

If compiler needs to instantiate `IsContainer<SomeType>` it would need to check if `SomeType` is `std::list<T>::iterator` for some type T. Since `list<T>::iterator` is some independent type (theoretically) from `list<T>` the only option to do it is to enumerate all the possible types (including infinite number of template instantiations), which is obviously impossible.