# Disallow function template instantiation with iterator parameter

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, c++14, function-templates

I have a function template which takes a templated parameter:

```
template <class R>
RefT<R> make_ref(R& res) {
    return RefT<R>(&res);
}
```

I either want to prevent `R` from being any kind of iterator, or, if this is easier, I want to have a overload that the compiler will prefer to use for iterators which calls make_ref again with the iterator dereferenced.

Best approach would be combining the two, so the compiler prefers using iterator specific overload, and refuses to use the non-specific version.

I would like consumers of the code to be able to call `make_ref(something)` without having to think about whether the `something` is an iterator or not - I just need to do something different if it is, and if that's not possible, give a useful error message to the consumer.

Comment: What do you mean by `iterator` ? `operator *`, `++`, (and so pointer)... ?

Comment: SFINAE or tag dispatching is the solution.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think I'm only talking about a naive understanding of what iterator means in c++, not things that can be treated as iterators, although if it's easier to also deal with such cases, that would be swell, but I'm afraid I don't really know what that entails.

Comment: @LyndenShields "Iterator in C++" means "anything on which you can call `*` and `++` and obtain results which satisfy a few conditions" (and/or other things, based on the iterator category).

Answer (score 4):

First the traits (you may have to tweak it with your requirements):

```
template <typename T>
auto is_iterator_impl(T* it)
-> decltype(**it, ++(*it), (*it) == (*it), std::true_type());

template <typename T>
auto is_iterator_impl(...) -> std::false_type;

template <typename T>
using is_an_iterator = decltype(is_iterator_impl<T>(0));
```

Note: using `std::iterator_traits<IT>` may be a good alternative.

With SFINAE, you may do

```
template <class R>
std::enable_if_t<!is_an_iterator<R>::value, RefT<R>>
make_ref(R& res) {
    return RefT<R>(&res);
}

template <class R>
std::enable_if_t<is_an_iterator<R>::value && !std::is_pointer<R>::value, RefT<R>> // you may want to change return type
make_ref(R& res) {
    // Implementation for iterator
}

template <class R>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<R>::value, RefT<R>> // you may want to change return type
make_ref(R& res) {
    // Implementation for iterator
}
```

Note: as you want to manage pointer differently, I also use `std::is_pointer` in addition to the custom `is_an_iterator`.

Note: The conditions should not have overlap, else you have conflict.

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/y3g2mM)

Comment: I do need to handle pointers that aren't iterators differently.
Also, is the second of your enable_if_t supposed to be R or RefT<R>?

Comment: I don't know the wanted signature, but you should know :-)

Comment: @LyndenShields "pointers that aren't iterators"? a pointer is an iterator

Comment: I have had a realisation, as per advice from @m.s. - the use case I'm having trouble with isn't actually iterators to objects, it's actually iterators to pointers to objects.
Would it be possible to overload for iterators-to-pointers-to-objects?

Comment: This might mean my question is 'invalid'

Comment: @LyndenShields you might ask a new question which highlights this detail

Comment: @LyndenShields: `std::is_pointer<std::iterator_traits<IT>::value_type>>::value` may help in that case

Comment: With the second argument to enable_if_t, is that what I want the return type to be if the first argument is 'true'?

Comment: @LyndenShields: yes, `std::enable_if_t<true, T>` is `T`

Comment: I can't manage to get around this error:
`error C2923: 'std::is_pointer': 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::value_type' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'`

Comment: @LyndenShields: I added a [live Demo](http://ideone.com/y3g2mM) (with `std::decltype` typo fixed).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83233/discussion-between-lynden-shields-and-jarod42).

Comment: So, is this thing vetted and legit, following the discussion? And is this C++11 or C++14?

Comment: @einpoklum: code is valid, use `.._t<..>` version for c++14, and `typename ..<..>` for c++11

Answer (score 2):

I used `is_iterator` from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4336298/678093

This traits struct is used with SFINAE to only enable `make_ref` for non-iterator types:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
struct is_iterator
{   
    static T makeT();
    typedef void * twoptrs[2];  // sizeof(twoptrs) > sizeof(void *)
    static twoptrs & test(...); // Common case
    template<class R> static typename R::iterator_category * test(R); // Iterator
    template<class R> static void * test(R *); // Pointer

    static const bool value = sizeof(test(makeT())) == sizeof(void *); 
};


// just to make it compile
template <typename R>
struct RefT{};

template <class R, typename std::enable_if<!is_iterator<R>::value>::type* = nullptr>
RefT<R> make_ref(R& res)
{
    return RefT<R>(&res);
}

int main()
{
    int* a;
    make_ref(a); // fails to compile

    int b;
    make_ref(b); // compiles once RefT is correct
    return 0;
}
```

An alernative solution is to use [`std::iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits):

```
template <class R, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename  std::iterator_traits<R>::value_type, void>::value>::type* = nullptr>
RefT<R> make_ref(R& res)
{
    return RefT<R>(&res);
}
```

Comment: Can you compare and contrast with the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

This could also be done by using SFINAE with `std::iterator_traits`, would handle all cases that previous answers handle (pointers and types having `internal` `iterator_category` `typedef`) but:

- no need to write your own traits (like `is_iterator`) to do this, or at least most of the template machinery is encapsulated in `iterator_traits`
- could also handle potential user defined iterators that were having their own `iterator_traits` specialization without using the generic `iterator_category` `typedef`, not sure if this relevant/legal technique but definitely possible

Comment: So, can you give an appropriate definition of an `is_iterator<T>` trait here?