# Asserting a Template Argument is an Iterator/Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, static-assert, enable-if

I have a templatized function that takes in pointers.

```
template <typename T>
void foo(const T* bar){}
```

How can I change `foo` to ensure that I am being passed an iterator/pointer? I assume there is a `static_assert` or an `enable_if` way of doing this, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Why don't you simply on implicit interfaces provided by templates mechanisms ? Just do your function body as if you were passed an iterator/pointer and it'll work for everything "looking like" so.

Comment: @Ninetainedo If I intend on exposing this function in my interface I need to do some defensive programming. Ideally providing the used of the interface information that `foo` was implemented incorrectly.

Comment: If you really want to do so, I know there is a `std::is_pointer` type_trait but I don't know about iterators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `std::iterator_traits` to check if it is an iterator (or pointer)

```
template <typename IT>
decltype(std::iterator_traits<IT>::iterator_category{}, void())
foo(IT bar);
```

Comment: This seems to be the correct solution: "If Iterator does not have the five member types difference_type, value_type, pointer, reference, and iterator_category, then this template has no member types (std::iterator_traits is SFINAE-friendly)" [[source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits)]

Answer (score 0):

To check for a pointer, you can use [`std::is_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pointer). To check for an iterator, you can define your own `is_iterator` trait as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12032923/1829930). If you combine these two, you get:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iterator>

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct is_iterator
{
   static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template<typename T>
struct is_iterator<T, typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type, void>::value>::type>
{
   static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template<class T>
void test(T t) {
  static_assert(std::is_pointer<T>::value || is_iterator<T>::value,
                "T must be pointer or iterator");
}
```