# Concept as_same identity fail

Tags: c++, c++20, type-traits, c++-concepts

I have a nice type traits that check if a type `T` is an iterator:

- demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/vUZ2hjQq6i9nlXFd
- stack post with explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67822208/9063139

I try to do the same but with concept. My first attempt was:

```
template<typename T>
concept isIterator = requires(T a) {
    { typename std::iterator_traits<T>::difference_type{} }   ->   std::same_as<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::difference_type>;
    { typename std::iterator_traits<T>::pointer{} }           ->   std::same_as<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::pointer>;
    { typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type{} }        ->   std::same_as<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type>;
    { typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category{} } ->   std::same_as<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category>;
    // this line trigger the assert for
    //  static_assert(is_iterator_v<std::vector<int>::iterator>);
    //  static_assert(is_iterator_v<int*>);
    { typename std::iterator_traits<T>::reference{} }         ->   std::same_as<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::reference>;

};

// default case
template <class T>
struct is_iterator : std::false_type
{
};


// specialization
template <isIterator It>
struct is_iterator<It> : std::true_type
{
};

template <class T>
constexpr bool is_iterator_v = is_iterator<T>::value;
```

Demo : https://wandbox.org/permlink/shrJpZPIlS0pXKak

But it fails on:

```
static_assert(is_iterator_v<std::vector<int>::iterator>);
static_assert(is_iterator_v<int*>);
```

And passes on:

```
static_assert(is_iterator_v<std::vector<int>::const_iterator>);
static_assert(is_iterator_v<std::list<double>::const_iterator>);
static_assert(!is_iterator_v<std::list<double>>);
static_assert(!is_iterator_v<int>);
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Why my concept didn't match for `std::vector<int>::iterator` and `int*` ?
2. <del>`static_assert(is_iterator_v<std::vector<int>::const_iterator>);` works but a reference is not default constructible, so how can it pass the  `{ typename std::iterator_traits<T>::reference{} }` requirement ?</del> Thx @cpplearner

---

Note : I know that I can just do:

```
template<typename T>
concept isIterator = requires(T a) {
     typename std::iterator_traits<T>::difference_type;
     typename std::iterator_traits<T>::pointer;
     typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type;
     typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category;
     typename std::iterator_traits<T>::reference;
};
```

And it works like a charm, but I would like to understand why my first attempt fail.

Comment: A `const int&` is constructible from `{}`. This creates a temporary `const int` copy-initialized from `{}` and bind the reference to the temporary. [\[dcl.init.list\]/(3.10)](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#3.10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fails with `std::vector<int>::iterator` and `int*` because:

- `std::iterator_traits<int*>::reference == int&`
- `std::iterator_traits<const int*>::reference == int&`
- `int&{}` does not compile (where `const int&{}` does)

So `{ typename std::iterator_traits<T>::reference{} }` fails for these types. It can be fixed with :

```
 { std::declval<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::reference>() }         ->   std::same_as<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::reference>;
```